# Flutter: how to add icon to text?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add an icon with text. I didn't find any clear answer. Please suggest to me how to do this in a flutter. Just like this one.

[image: Desired image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here are two approaches, depending on exactly what you want.

### RichText with WidgetSpan

Using RichText you can mix TextSpans with WidgetSpans. WidgetSpan allows you to place any Flutter widget inline with the text. For example:

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Created with '),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.airport_shuttle),
        ),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: 'By Michael'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Will give the following:

[image]

(Note: MaterialIcons did not include a heart when I answered, but does now with `Icons.favorite`)

This is a good general purpose solution, but for your specific example there's something simpler...

### Emoji

Flutter's text supports Emoji out of the box. So you can do this:

```dart
Center(
  child: Text(
    'Created with ❤ ️by Michael',
    maxLines: 1,
  ),
),
```

And you get this:

[image]

You can also use Unicode escapes in the string and get the same result:

```dart
'Created with \u2764️ by Michael'
```

Note that not all fonts have support for the full set of Emoji, so make sure you test on a variety of devices or use a specific font (see other answer below).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Emojis, in android not all emojis are supported (depending on OS version).

For full emoji compatibility you can use the google free font Noto Color Emoji at https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye-color

- Add it to the fonts folder
- add in pubspec.yaml

```
    fonts:
    - family: NotoEmoji
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
          weight: 400
```

- use with TextStyle

  `Text("", TextStyle(fontFamily: 'NotoEmoji'))`